# ueye_cam calibration and parameters

Tags: ros, calibration, camera, ueye-cam, ueye

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use `ueye_cam` package to control two uEye cameras: a UI122xSE-C and a UI223xSE-C. I've installed the IDS driver and I can use it to open both cameras. I'm trying to use `rgb8.launch` to control the UI122xSE camera first. However, I get the following warning whenever I run this launch with that camera:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/auto_exposure
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/auto_frame_rate
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/auto_gain
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/auto_white_balance
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/binning
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/blue_gain
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/camera_id
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/camera_intrinsics_file
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/camera_name
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/camera_parameters_file
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/camera_topic
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/color_mode
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/exposure
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/ext_trigger_mode
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/flash_delay
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/flash_duration
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/flip_lr
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/flip_upd
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/frame_rate
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/gain_boost
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/green_gain
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/image_height
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/image_left
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/image_top
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/image_width
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/master_gain
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/pixel_clock
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/red_gain
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/sensor_scaling
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/subsampling
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/white_balance_blue_offset
 * /ueye_cam_nodelet/white_balance_red_offset

NODES
  /
    nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    ueye_cam_nodelet (nodelet/nodelet)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [12676]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 51881744-30ea-11e5-a04e-001cbf994206
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [12689]
started core service [/rosout]
process[nodelet_manager-2]: started with pid [12701]
[ INFO] [1437621866.152417884]: Initializing nodelet with 2 worker threads.
process[ueye_cam_nodelet-3]: started with pid [12719]
[ INFO] [1437621866.398732306]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/labrobotica/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1437621868.876056765]: Could not load UEye camera 'camera' sensor parameters file /home/labrobotica/.ros/camera_conf/camera.ini (IS_FILE_WRITE_OPEN_ERROR)
[ WARN] [1437621868.876325235]: Camera configuration loaded into an unsupported color mode; switching to MONO8.
[ WARN] [1437621868.932790723]: Internal image scaling is not supported by camera
[ INFO] [1437621869.028831010]: UEye camera 'camera' initialized on topic /camera/image_raw
Width:          752
Height:         480
Left Pos.:      -1
Top Pos.:       -1
Color Mode:     rgb8
Subsampling:        1
Binning:        1
Sensor Scaling:     1
Auto Gain:      1
Master Gain:        0
Red Gain:       0
Green Gain:     1
Blue Gain:      16
Gain Boost:     0
Auto Exposure:      1
Exposure (ms):      33
Auto White Balance: 1
WB Red Offset:      0
WB Blue Offset:     0
Flash Delay (us):   0
Flash Duration (us):    1000
Ext Trigger Mode:   0
Auto Frame Rate:    0
Frame Rate (Hz):    30.0087
Pixel Clock (MHz):  25
Mirror Image Upside Down:   0
Mirror Image Left Right:    0
```

How can I get the parameters? How can I calibrate the camera?

EDIT: I also have another question regarding the control of both cameras at the same time. Do I need just to modify rgb8.launch adding another ueye_cam_nodelet (like ueye_cam_nodelet2) with another camera_name (like camera2)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214368/ueye_cam-calibration-and-parameters/) by [Pinchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10766/pinchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-07-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Re - parameters:  which parameters do you want to get? If you are referring to the warning about MONO8: http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure

Re - calibration: http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration

Re - multiple uEye cameras: if you want them to operate independently, then yes you need to duplicate the launch file, and change the node name, camera namespace, and camera ID. If you want to synchronize the exposure of both cameras, see: http://wiki.ros.org/ueye_cam#Camera_Synchronization

---

Originally posted by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) with karma: 193 on 2015-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1